# How do I increase YouTube API quota?

Tags: youtube-data-api

I am trying to increase the YouTube Data API v3 quota on my account. I am taken to the [following url](https://services.google.com/fb/forms/ytapiquotarequest/). At the bottom of the page is a captcha which says "reCAPTCHA V1 IS SHUTDOWN. Direct site owners to g.co/recaptcha/upgrade". I cannot proceed past this.

Is it possible to pay for more quota? Or do I Just need to request an increase?

Comment: I had the same problem :(

Comment: I have the same issue as well. No help from Google whatsoever

Comment: The problem no longer seems relevant.